# HABTM fails to fulfil relationship with VARCHAR Primary Key in related tables

Tags: cakephp, has-and-belongs-to-many

I have a schema with multiple HABTM relationships.
Am baking nearly all code at this stage to test schema.

I note that unless the related tables have INT primary keys then the HATBM relationships do not fulfil correctly.

I need to use some PK's that are VARCHAR(50). HABTM does not appear to correctly update the join table if a PK is VARCHAR(50).

Anyone aware of a workaround for this?
am using cake 2.2.1 on Centos 6.3

Answer (score 1):

CakePHP only natively supports using `INT` or `CHAR(36)` primary keys. In order to use `VARCHAR(50)` as a PK, you'll need to use the [`$primaryKey`](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/model-attributes.html#primarykey) attribute and do any generation/manipulation of your PK in a model function (such as `beforeSave`) or in the controller:

```
if($this->data) {
  $this->data['SomeModel'][$this->SomeModel->primaryKey] = 'your key value';
}
```